# Конструкция value='' select в Хроме

Tags: google-chrome, javascript

В Хроме не срабатывает конструкция

```
var s = document.getElementById('s2');
if (!s) return;
s.value='';
```

s2 - select;

Как правильно для Хрома прописать такую конструкцию?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хром здесь не при чем. Присваивать `s.value` значение в данном случае — нестандарт, у [`<select>`'ов](http://www.tigir.com/javascript_select.htm) с одним вариантом для выбора используется свойство `selectedIndex`. Соответственно, `s.selectedIndex = -1;`.

С использованием jQuery: `$("#s2").prop("selectedIndex", -1);` (для jQuery старее 1.6 вместо `prop` используется `attr`).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, уже нашел сам. Просто в опере на ура прокатывало просто присваивание значения. Только у меня есть в выборе вариант пустого значения сделал так: `s.selectedIndex = 0;`